# Merge two DataFrames with key over-write

Tags: python, pandas

I have implemented a custom merge of 2 pandas DataFrames, but only mutates the first.

The new columns will be the union of the original columns and the new keys will be union of original keys. Additionally, the second DataFrame values will overwrite the first DataFrame if the keys match.

```py
def merge_dataframes(df1, df2):
    for header in set(df2) - (set(df1) & set(df2)):
        df1[header] = None

    old_keys = df2.index.isin(df1.index)
    new_keys = ~old_keys

    df1.update(df2[old_keys])
    df1 = df1.append(df2[new_keys], sort=True)

    return df1
```

This is tested as follows:

```
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data=["Test1", "Test2"])
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=["Test3", "Test4"])

    # this should simply overwrite df1 with df2
    new_df = merge_dataframes(df1, df2)
    assert (new_df == df2).all()[0]

    df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data=["Test1", "Test2"])
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=["Test3", "Test4"], index=["a", "b"])

    # this should simply overwrite df1 with df2
    new_df = merge_dataframes(df1, df2)
    expected_df = pandas.DataFrame(data=["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"], index=[0, 1, "a", "b"])
    assert (new_df == expected_df).all()[0]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with less code?

Comment: This looks like `df1= pd.concat((df1,df2)).drop_duplicates(keep='last')` let me know If I am wrong also if you can extend the example, that'd be great.

Comment: Also may be you can try `df1 = pd.concat((df1,df2)).groupby(level=0).last()`